# Problema ao criar uma conexão entre PHP e PostgreSQl

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, apache, wampserver

Não estou conseguindo realizar a conexão com o banco de dados PostgreSQl.
Segue o código:

```
<?php

class Conexao {
    private $usuario;
    private $senha;
    private $banco;
    private $servidor; 
    private $porta;
    private static $pdo;
    //Método construtor conexao
    public function __construct() {
        $this->servidor = "localhost";
        $this->banco = "emporio";
        $this->usuario = "postgres";
        $this->senha = "gui1234"; 
        $this->porta = "5432";
    }
    //Método para conexão
    public function conectar(){
        try {
            //verificando se atributo pdo está estanciado
            if (is_null(self::$pdo)) {
                //Estanciando conexao
                self::$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=".$this->servidor.";dbname=".$this->banco, $this->usuario, $this->senha,$this->porta);

            }
            return self::$pdo;// se já estiver estanciado, retorna.

        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo "erro".ex->getMessage;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Defina "conecte direito", por favor. Deu algo erro?

Answer (score 1):

Para se instanciar um objeto PDO você deve fazer o seguinte (o parâmetro após a senha é as opções de conexão http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

```
self::$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=".$this->servidor.";port=".$this->porta.";dbname=".$this->banco, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
```

Caso queira utilizar a opção de configuração você pode fazer assim

```
$options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
self::$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=".$this->servidor.";port=".$this->porta.";dbname=".$this->banco, $this->usuario, $this->senha,$options);
```

Outra coisa que vi que precisa de ajuste é o trecho

```
catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo "erro".ex->getMessage; // É echo "erro". $ex->getMessage();
    }
```